# Highlighting a new mySQL entry in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Well in PHP I am working with MYSQL databases, and able to insert data into the mysql database through a PHP form.I need to list the entries that are already in the database alphabetically. Now after adding data  that data needs to appear red in the table of information. Here is the code I have so far, but IDK how to make the entry in the table red.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        width: 500px;
        clear: both;
    }
       .container input {
        width: 100%;
       clear: both;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//Vars
$movieName = $_POST['movieName'];
$movieCategory = $_POST['movieCategory'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$stock = $_POST['stock'];
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'movies') or DIE('SHIP BE BROKE!');
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM `movies` ORDER BY `movieName` ASC");
$queryInsert = "INSERT INTO `movies`.`movies` (`ID`, `movieName`, `movieCategory`,         `price`, `stock`) VALUES (NULL, '$movieName', '$movieCategory', '$price', '$stock');";

echo '<table border="1" width="100%"><tr bgcolor="#d1d1d1"><td>Movie Name</td>         <td>Category</td><td>Price</td><td>Stock</b></td></tr>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['movieName'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['movieCategory'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['price'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['stock'].'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tr></table></table>';
echo '<h3>Insert a Movie into the database</h3>';
if($movieName == null){?>
<div class="container">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
Movie Name: <input type="text" name="movieName">
Movie Category: <input type="text" name="movieCategory">
Price: <input type="text" name="price">
Stock: <input type="text" name="stock">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<?php
}

if($price != null){
mysqli_query($dbc, $queryInsert) or DIE ('YOUR QUERY SUCKS!');
echo '<font color="red">';
echo $movieName.', '. $movieCategory.', '.$price.', '.$stock;
echo '</font>';
 }


mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean if that data is already present then u want that in red ?

Comment: @m.chaundhry no I want the latest entry to appear red in the table.

Comment: @DtrollMC usually you should use `<tr class="new">` with the appropriate css style i.e. `.new {color: red;}` in your stylesheet. But you've got to detect after the roundtrip to the server that this special row is new ... You could of course add your new row with an AJAX call and simply add this new row with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you need to call  last_insert_id() function so you can highlight the new entry

```
if($price != null){
last_insert_id($price); 
echo '<font color="red">';
echo $movieName.', '. $movieCategory.', '.$price.', '.$stock;
echo '</font>';
}
```